# How read large amount of numbers?

Tags: c++, c

I need to read large amount (up to 2^24) of big numbers (max 22 chars each) in C/C++. How to perform such a read? Numbers are separated by space and I must read all until new line. Use getch() and fill an array or there is some smarter solution?

Comment: Memory map the file, and use pointer arithmetic?

Comment: in `C`, or `C++`? if C++, use streams and vectors.

Comment: From `stdin` or from a file? And Do you want to use C or C++?

Comment: this need to be read from standard input. Mike, TZHX it can be C++

Answer (score 4):

What are these "numbers"? If they are integers, there's typically no built-in support in C for such large numbers; you will need some library for "bignum" support. If they're floating-point, you can try `double` but the precision will probably not be enough.

It's hard to be more specific without knowing more about your data, consider showing some of the numbers in the question since it's very vague otherwise.

Comment: I will use GMP to handle them, so my worry is to read them as strings at the moment

Comment: generally they will be integers

Answer (score 2):

If your read is single-threaded, you can use [`getchar_unlocked()`](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/getchar_unlocked.3.asp), which avoids the overhead of locking the stream for each operation. Go character-by-character, accumulate the number, and wait for a space. When you see the space, save the number, and zero out the current value:

```
int *data = new int[MAX_LEN];
int *ptr = data;
int ch;
*ptr = 0;
while ((ch = getchar_unlocked()) != '\n') {
    if (ch == ' ') {
        ptr++;
        *ptr = 0;
    } else {
        *ptr = (*ptr *10) + (ch -'0');
    }
}
```

Of course this fragment ignores the "unimportant" stuff such as error checking, but it is OK when your input is "sanitized". For example, something like this can be used to save on I/O costs with an ACM online judge.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you'll need a proper type to store the integer, as it's larger than 64 bits int, you'll probably need a structured type. You can either write your own or use a library, such as

http://gmplib.org/

read the documentation of it for usage.

Then, you'd need to make it clear what you want to do with the numbers: sum up, convert, search or transfer? Once you know, you can operate on the data type you used for the integer.

Comment: I will have to make some basic computations (like average), using the GMP you mentioned

Comment: You will possibly need a string buffer too, to store chars before validating and parsing them into numbers.